# Dagger2/Android: My @FragmentScoped subcomponents are being recreated with each rotation

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

Originally posted as an [issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1113) on the Dagger2 repo.

**Summary**: I have an activity with one fragment that has `setRetainInstance(true)`. Despite the fragment being retained, every time I call `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)` on it, it injects *new instances* of its dependencies. It looks like the fragment subcomponent is being recreated (I think?) each time the activity subcomponent is recreated (on rotation).

Is this *expected*, or is my graph misconfigured?

I have an app component like so:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ActivitiesModule::class,
    AndroidViewInjectionModule::class,
    NetModule::class
])
interface MainApplicationComponent {

    fun inject(app: MainApplication)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): MainApplicationComponent
        @BindsInstance fun app(app: Context): Builder
        // ... other things ...
    }
}
```

`ActivitiesModule` looks like:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivitiesModule {
    // ... other things ...

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [
        UpgradeActivityModule::class,
        UpgradeFragmentModule::class
    ]) abstract fun upgradeActivity(): UpgradeActivity
}
```

`UpgradeFragmentModule`:

```
@Module
abstract class UpgradeFragmentModule {
    @FragmentScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [
        UpgradeActivity.UpgradeFragmentModule::class,
        ViewInjectorModule::class
    ]) abstract fun upgradeFragment(): UpgradeFragment
}
```

And `UpgradeActivity.UpgradeFragmentModule` (this is all very much WIP, sorry for weird names):

```
@Module
abstract class UpgradeFragmentModule {
    @Binds @FragmentScoped abstract fun bindUpgradeModel(model: UpgradeModel): UpgradeMvp.Model
    @Binds @FragmentScoped abstract fun bindUpgradePresenter(presenter: UpgradePresenter): UpgradeMvp.Presenter
    // ... other things ...

    @Module
    companion object {
        @Provides @JvmStatic fun provideResources(activityProvider: Provider<UpgradeActivity>): Resources {
            return activityProvider.get().resources
        }
        // ... other things ...
    }
}
```

I experimented further and tried to make my `@FragmentScoped` elements direct descendants of my `@Singleton` app component, but it has the same issue. In fact, if I just inject my fragment twice in a row, I get new instances each time. Clearly I'm doing something wrong....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I strongly encourage you to simply have a look at the Dagger Android [source code](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/DispatchingAndroidInjector.java#L75), since it's only a few classes that do all the work.*

> [...] every time I call AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this) on it, it injects new instances of its dependencies. It looks like the fragment subcomponent is being recreated [...]

That's exactly what's going on.
To give an inaccurate and simplified summary, you register your Subcomponent.Builders in a Map, and when you call `AndroidInjection.inject()` it will look up and create the right Builder and Component, with which it will then inject the object.

You should never inject objects multiple times as this will accomplish nothing in the best case, or lead to errors/bugs otherwise. Scopes are *per component*, so if you recreate the component, you recreate every object within its scope along with it. And calling `AndroidInjection.inject()` will always create a new component.

---

You don't go into detail about what you inject when and where, but if you keep the same fragment object around, you should not inject it again.

> [...] and tried to make my @FragmentScoped elements direct descendants of my @Singleton app component, but it has the same issue.

That's what you should do. If you use `setRetainInstance(true)`, then the fragment should most likely *not* be a Subcomponent of your `UpgradeActivity`, or it will leak the reference when the Activity gets recreated.

> if I just inject my fragment twice in a row, I get new instances each time.

If you call `AndroidInjection.inject()` then it will create a new component with every call, so I assume that's what you did and observed. If you inject an object twice with the same component, then any scoped objects will be the same. Unscoped objects will always be created for every use. But in any case, you should never inject an object more than once.

Comment: I tried to not inject my retained fragment a second time, but I ended up leaking the activity. Somehow one of the classes in dagger.android was retaining a reference. I'll recreate the scenario and post a stacktrace. Your explanation seems correct, though.

Comment: Ok! Whatever was causing the leak, I seem to have solved with fiddling with my dagger components a bit. I think I was injecting an activity reference somewhere, but I've gotten rid of that. FWIW, before `dagger.android`, I used to retain static references to my _subcomponents_, not my _builders_, and so I just missed that trick. The world makes sense again!